# ant "c:\jdk1.5 does not exist"

Tags: ant, java

При сборке проекта Ant'ом получаю ошибку:

> D:\PS2\Projects\Project\MainModule\mainmodule.xml:227: c:\jdk1.5 does
>   not exist.    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:483)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet.iterator(FileSet.java:69)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Union.getCollection(Union.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Union.getCollection(Union.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.BaseResourceCollectionContainer.cacheCollection(BaseResourceCollectionContainer.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.BaseResourceCollectionContainer.iterator(BaseResourceCollectionContainer.java:142)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path.iterator(Path.java:710)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path.iterator(Path.java:704)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Union.getCollection(Union.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Union.getCollection(Union.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.BaseResourceCollectionContainer.cacheCollection(BaseResourceCollectionContainer.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.BaseResourceCollectionContainer.iterator(BaseResourceCollectionContainer.java:142)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path.iterator(Path.java:710)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path.iterator(Path.java:704)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Union.getCollection(Union.java:123)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Union.list(Union.java:86)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path.list(Path.java:378)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path.addExisting(Path.java:331)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path.addExisting(Path.java:319)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path.concatSpecialPath(Path.java:580)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.Path.concatSystemClasspath(Path.java:532)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.getCompileClasspath(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.setupJavacCommandlineSwitches(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.setupModernJavacCommandlineSwitches(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:340)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.JavacExternal.execute(JavacExternal.java:49)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1134)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:180)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)

При этом строка 227, которая указана как та, в которой произошла ошибка, выглядит следующим образом:

```
 executable="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5/bin/javac"
```

из задачи:

```
<javac destdir="${castorbeans.output.dir}" debug="${compiler.debug}"
               nowarn="${compiler.generate.no.warnings}" memorymaximumsize="${compiler.max.memory}" fork="true"
               executable="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5/bin/javac">
            <compilerarg line="${compiler.args.castorbeans}"/>
            <bootclasspath refid="castorbeans.module.bootclasspath"/>
            <classpath refid="castorbeans.module.classpath"/>

            <src refid="castorbeans.module.sourcepath"/>
            <patternset refid="excluded.from.compilation.castorbeans"/>
</javac>
```

В чём причина того, что путь к jdk определяется как "`c:\jdk1.5`", а не "`C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5/bin/javac`"?

Comment: пробелы в пути могут вызывать очень странные ошибки. попробуйте указать путь без пробела.